# Utilização dos Pseudo Classes em CSS

Tags: css, css3, aplicação-web, pseudo-classes

Eu sei que as pseudos classes são: `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` e `:active`, mas eu gostaria de saber se tem como utilizar as pseudos classes por meio de *class*, *id* ou *inline*. Às vezes eu não quero utilizar um `:hover` em todos os `h1`, somente em alguns. Como eu faço para tal escolha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode tanto utilizar em `tags` específicas, como em `class`, `id` e até `tags` específicas de um `id`, por exemplo:

```css
p:hover{
 font-size: 20px;
}
.paragrafo:hover{
 color: #ff0026;
}
#p1:hover, #p2:hover, #p3:hover{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #ff0026;
}
#paragrafo h3:hover{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Tag</h2>
   <div>
      <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
      <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
      <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
   </div>
   <h2>Class</h2>
   <div>
      <h4 class="paragrafo">Primeiro parágrafo</h4>
      <h4 class="paragrafo">Segundo parágrafo</h4>
      <h4 class="paragrafo">Terceiro parágrafo</h4>
   </div>
   <h2>Id</h2>
   <div>
      <h4 id="p1">Primeiro parágrafo</h4>
      <h4 id="p2">Segundo parágrafo</h4>
      <h4 id="p3">Terceiro parágrafo</h4>
   </div>
   <h2>Tag de um Id</h2>
   <div id="paragrafo">
      <h3>Primeiro parágrafo</h4>
      <h3>Segundo parágrafo</h4>
      <h3>Terceiro parágrafo</h4>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entendi , muito obrigado pelo ajuda .

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a pseudo `:not` para excluir a classe que não será afetada pelo `:hover`:

```css
h1:hover:not(.semhover){
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>h1 primeiro</h1>
<h1 class="semhover">h1 segundo</h1>
<h1>h1 terceiro</h1>
```

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda .

Comment: De nada. Antonio, quando vc faz uma pergunta e recebe respostas, é importante sempre procurar marcar ✔️ em apenas 1 resposta para que a sua pergunta seja dada como resolvida. Pelo que vi no seu histórico, vc já fez 4 perguntas e em nenhuma vc escolheu uma resposta. O sistema do site é assim: vc faz uma pergunta, recebe uma ou mais respostas, escolhe a que achou melhor e marca ✔️ nela. Vc também pode votar nas respostas se achar que foram úteis.